# npm start, project wont start but used to work, no changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, npm

I did not make any changes to my project other than download and started to use Atom editor but now my project won't even start. This is the npm debug log that it's giving me. I recently installed visual studios too which is really the only difference in the time I tried running them, didn't edit or add any and yet doesn't start anymore. I tried running a basic project just from the default express and that won't run either

```
`0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@2.15.8
3 info using node@v4.4.7
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info prestart HelloNode@0.0.0
6 info start HelloNode@0.0.0
7 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 info HelloNode@0.0.0 Failed to exec start script
9 verbose stack Error: HelloNode@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
9 verbose stack spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe\ ENOENT
9 verbose stack     at exports._errnoException (util.js:873:11)
9 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
9 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
9 verbose stack     at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
9 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)
10 verbose pkgid HelloNode@0.0.0
11 verbose cwd C:\Users\andreww\Desktop\Projects\HelloNode
12 error Windows_NT 10.0.10586
13 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
14 error node v4.4.7
15 error npm  v2.15.8
16 error file C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe\
17 error path C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe\
18 error code ELIFECYCLE
19 error errno ENOENT
20 error syscall spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe\
21 error HelloNode@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
21 error spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe\ ENOENT
22 error Failed at the HelloNode@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
22 error This is most likely a problem with the HelloNode package,
22 error not with npm itself.
22 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
22 error     node ./bin/www
22 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
22 error     npm bugs HelloNode
22 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
22 error
22 error     npm owner ls HelloNode
22 error There is likely additional logging output above.
23 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
`
```

Comment: can you share the `package.json` ? Also, /bin/www file exist in project folder ?

Comment: yeah here is the package.json   `{
  "name": "HelloNode",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.15.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.4",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "repair": "^0.1.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
}`

Comment: and heres thebin/www http://pastebin.com/5fNNgMuk

Comment: Did you try to launch the project from Atom terminal? If so, please read https://discuss.atom.io/t/spawn-cmd-exe-enoent/19595/7

Comment: @type node and hit enter, see if the node console works.

Comment: typing node in the console works

Comment: Did it work when clean project is downloaded(without node_module )? Did it work on from yarn (did U tried yarn install ? )